# Flask+MongoEngine: Set MongoEngine Document Field as Unique in pre existing Document

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have an app created with Flask+MongoEngine and I have the a 'User Document' like this:

```
class User(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField(max_length=MAX_USERNAME_CHARS)
    name =  db.StringField(max_length=70)
    #[...]
    email = db.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True)
#[...]
meta = {
    'indexes': ['-created_at', 'email'],
    'ordering': ['-created_at']
}
#[...]
```

So far I've been checking for duplication of "username" and "email" in the Controller but I still have in mongo these duplicate fields for some users and now I want to set this fields ("username" and "email") to be Unique, not nullable and required.

I was searching on docs and now I know that can I do this whit this declaration:

```
email = db.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True, unique=True)
```

but MongoEngine do not set this again if the document was created before.

So, I'm looking for a method to me from now (once solved already duplicates) not re-occur duplicate fields.

The app it is in production with a lot of users registered.
I can use mongo console to set some index or some.

Answer (score 1):

First off, before trying anything, **do a full database backup**!

You will want to create an unique index on the email field to enforce its uniqueness. If there are no duplicate emails, the query will succeed. You will get an error if duplicate email addresses already exist in the database (this shouldn't be the case).

Enter the mongo console and create the index:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

This creates an *ascending* index on the `email` field (hence the 1; `-1` would represent a descending index). This makes searching and sorting emails much faster. It also makes it unique (which is what your actual goal was!), so that queries attempting to insert a document with an existing email will fail.

See [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the official MongoDB site for more details.